# Automatically update client on MongoDB change

Tags: mongodb, socket.io

I am continuously feeding a mongoDB database from an external java application with high frequency. Each element that I add to the database is a n-dimensional vector like:

```
{
"timestamp":12345678
"values": 
    {
    "x1": 10.4
    "x2": 0.3
    ...
    }
}
```

My goal is to build a client web application that display all the new value since the beginning of the connection.
For this purpose, I have implemented a small web app using Angular.js with Node.js+socket.io (seems to be a frequent combination) by adapting the standard "poll application". 
But now my problem is that I'm stuck because i would need to reload to have the new values.
**Is there a way to trigger some "event" on server side to indicate that new element have been added to a collection ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered Tailable Cursor over Mongo Oplog. I believe that is what you are looking for.
You can find the sample Usage [here](https://danielweberonline.wordpress.com/tag/tailable-cursors/)

Comment: Yes I've tried this, seems to be the best option ! Thank you for your answer.